# Servlet request.getServletPath

Tags: servlets, path-parameter

I am new to Servlet and I am trying to learn but I am facing a problem.

I have a servlet class and I want to do CRUD operation. I want each Operation redirected to a specific method. But I had a problem, it won't redirect. I tested via POSTman but whenever I tried to send a request it does not receive and nothing appears in my console.

Only the default works.

This is my *@WebServlet*("/budgets")

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("budgetController, doPost() Started");
        String action = request.getServletPath();
        System.out.println("doPost, action ==>" + action);

        switch (action) {

        case "/add": {
            addNewBudget(request, response);
            break;
        }
        case "/update": {
            updateBudget(request, response);
            break;
        }
        case "/delete": {
            deleteBudget(request, response);
            break;
        }
        case "/get": {
            getBudget(request, response);
            break;
        }

        case "/list": {
            getAllBudgets(request, response);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            getAllBudgets(request, response);
            break;
        }
```

I tried to change the *@WebServlet*("/budgets") but i couldn't resolve.

Comment: Take more care in your writing when posting here. Stack Overflow is not a casual chat-room. Your post might be read by thousands of people over many years, many of whom are non-native speakers of English. I did some edits on this post.

Comment: What is result of `System.out.println("doPost, action ==>" + action);`?  Or debug and step through the code to see the value that doesn't match any of the cases.

Comment: This seems like the hard way.  Why not just methods annotated with, for example, `@WebServlet("/budgets/add")` and `@WebServlet("/budgets/update")` etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Currently your servlet listens to one specific path `/budgets`.

To make the servlet listen to everything behind the budgets path, you should set the following URL pattern: `/budgets/*` in the WebServlet annotation.

In order to read the extra path information you should use the `getPathInfo()` method instead `getServletPath()` method.

However, the `getPathInfo()` may return `null` if there is no extra path information. You also should check for `null`.

So change your code to:

```
@WebServlet("/budgets/*")
....
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("budgetController, doPost() Started");
    String action = request.getPathInfo();
    System.out.println("doPost, action ==>" + action);

    if (action==null)
      action=new String();

    switch (action) {

    case "/add": {
        addNewBudget(request, response);
        break;
    }
    case "/update": {
        updateBudget(request, response);
        break;
    }
    case "/delete": {
        deleteBudget(request, response);
        break;
    }
    case "/get": {
        getBudget(request, response);
        break;
    }

    case "/list": {
        getAllBudgets(request, response);
        break;
    }
    default: {
        getAllBudgets(request, response);
        break;
    }
```